# Media upload via backend doen't work after moving site

Tags: uploads, media, migration

I have copied my site to a subdirectory for test purposes, everything works fine now. The only problem I have seen so far is the Media upload. When I try to upload a file I get a:

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2016/05. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

The wp-content folder has a 755 permission, the uploads folder also.

I tried to add this to my wp-config

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'uploads');
```

in the section before the table prefix is set, because I thought maybe I have to tell WP that the path changed

```
    define( 'UPLOADS', 'unterverzeichnis/wp-content/'.'uploads');
```

but I get the same error.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does the 2016 folder exist already? Does it have 755 permissions?

Comment: Yes to both of your questions. I created the folder manually, because I thought this might be the problem.

Comment: double check the media file url in settings > media, maybe it's still set to the old url which doesn't exist